# Moving app comments to page

Tags: facebook, comments

I've set up an app and I'm running comments on my website. I would now like to setup a Facabook page and display the comments made to the app. I've read this:

[Posting comments to Facebook Fan Page](http://facebook.stackoverflow.com/questions/8392659/posting-comments-to-facebook-fan-page)

Which shows me how to do this but i'm not sure that the comments will carry over to the page as they have been made to the app?

The same goes for 'likes'

Any ideas out there?

Answer (score 0):

No, they will not be carried over when you change the values in your plugin.

Comment: Thanks for your post. So what would be the best strategy to retain the likes and comments - a custom canvas possibly?

Comment: To retain, you need to maintain the original app, or download them into a datastore of your own.